# How to highlight a column instead of a row in javafx TableView when hover?

Tags: javafx, tableview

How to highlight a column instead of a row in javafx TableView when hover or click on it?

Comment: Are you referring to highlighting the entire column, the nth cell in each row, or just a particular cell in a particular row?

Comment: I am referring on how to highlight the entire column. 
As standard the row is highlighted when hover on it. 
I would like to highlight the column and not the row.

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution for this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaFX how to highlight TableColumn instead of TableRow when mouse is hovered to column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781987/javafx-how-to-highlight-tablecolumn-instead-of-tablerow-when-mouse-is-hovered-to)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend that you use [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) for this. You can inspect the scene graph and see all the css attributes for each element in it. This will allow you to easily identify the proper css hierarchy to use to style just the column rather than the row.

Then you can apply the appropriate styles with css for the hover or clicked states using the following css event selectors:

```
:hover
:armed
:pressed
:disabled
etc...
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but this link http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/ gives me 404 Not found. I have tried to find it on different sources, but without success.

Comment: that's strange. I just clicked the link and it works fine. try it again or just Google javafx scenic view.

Comment: Indeed, they were temporary down. Anyway, due to the fact that the TableView is organized in rows and the css for hover state is applied on these,all the cells have the same css class. So I could not find a solution using the proposed method. Thanks!